# How can I convert html emoji to text?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, unicode, emoji

I'm working with emojis, and I choose to store: `&#128514;` instead  into the database, which works fine.

How can I reload the text in a asp:TextBox and convert `&#128514;` into  ?

In database: `test &#128512;&#128513;&#128514;`

In text field I need: test  for edit purposes.

I think that a simple code resolve this issue like:

```
txtComment_Lmt.Text = Server.HtmlDecode("test &#128512;&#128513;&#128514;");
```

But this approach does not working, i known that emoji is related with unicode.

How can I convert emoji html entitity to something that work in edit mode on textbox?

Comment: but how did you get to  `&#128514;" ? what format is that. Can you show on your question how to got to that values. Perhaps it will show some leads.

Comment: I get this value on C# converting the emoji unicode to html entitie, but this is not my problem `code`  lValue_Cmt += "&#" + char.ConvertToUtf32(pValue_Cmt, lIndex) + ";          `code`

Comment: What's wrong on [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netcore-3.1) (as @Mikael already suggested)?

Comment: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method does not working, it returns the same string as input, i readed that C# native code does not work with html5 tags.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery i got the solution:

```
var ltxtComment_Lmt = document.getElementById('txtComment_Lmt');
ltxtComment_Lmt.value = $('<textarea />').html(ltxtComment_Lmt.value).text();
```

But i want this solution in C#, i readed that C# not working with html5 entities, i think that exist some easy solution to decode emoji html codes to a textbox.

Comment: This belongs as an edit to your question, not an answer. Stack overflow isn't a message board where you make a new entry every time you have something to add to a question or answer.

Comment: This is a answer, but not the answer i want, i just put this to show to other user's that is possible to solve the issue, i hope someone answer my question with C# code, thanks anyway.

Comment: No, i'm using jquery, and i want to solve with pure C# / javascript

Answer (score 1):

```cs
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("test &#128512;&#128513;&#128514;")
```

should give you the decoded string you are looking for.

Here is a simple test to check its behavior

```cs
public class TestEmoji 
{
  [Test]
  public void TestEncodedEmoji() 
  {
    var encoded = "test &#128512;&#128513;&#128514;";

    var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);

    decoded.Should().Be("test ");
  }
}
```

by the way I am not sure if you are working on ASP.NET Framework or ASP.NET Core. I tested it on Core.